# PyTorch: How to insert before a certain element

Tags: pytorch

Currently I have a 2D tensor, for each row, I want to insert a new element `e` before the first index of a specified value `v`. Additional information: cannot guarantee each row could have a such value. If there isn't, just append the element

Example: Supporse `e` is 0, `v` is 10, Given a tensor

```
[[9, 6, 5, 4, 10],
 [8, 7, 3, 5, 5],
 [4, 9, 10, 10, 10]]
```

I want to get

```
[[9, 6, 5, 4, 0, 10],
 [8, 7, 3, 5, 5, 0],
 [4, 9, 0, 10, 10, 10]]
```

Are there some Torch-style ways to do this? The worst case I can treat this as a trivial Python problem but I think the corresponding solution is a little time-consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't yet found a *full* PyTorch solution. I'll keep looking, but here is somewhere to start:

```
>>> v, e = 10, 0
>>> v, e = torch.tensor([v]), torch.tensor([e])

>>> x = torch.tensor([[ 9,  6,  5,  4, 10],
                      [ 8,  7,  3,  5,  5],
                      [ 4,  9, 10, 10, 10],
                      [10,  9,  7, 10,  2]])
```

To deal with the edge case where `v` is not found in one of the rows you can add a temporary column to `x`. This will ensure every row has a value `v` in it. We will use `x_` as a helper tensor:

```
>>> x_ = torch.cat([x, v.repeat(x.size(0))[:, None]], axis=1)
tensor([[ 9,  6,  5,  4, 10, 10],
        [ 8,  7,  3,  5,  5, 10],
        [ 4,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10],
        [10,  9,  7, 10,  2, 10]])
```

Find the indices of the first value `v` on each row:

```
>>> bp = (x_ == v).int().argmax(axis=1)
tensor([4, 5, 2, 0])
```

Finally, the easiest way to insert values at different positions in each row is with a list comprehension:

```
>>> torch.stack([torch.cat([xi[:bpi], e, xi[bpi:]]) for xi, bpi in zip(x, bp)])
tensor([[ 9,  6,  5,  4,  0, 10],
        [ 8,  7,  3,  5,  5,  0],
        [ 4,  9,  0, 10, 10, 10],
        [ 0, 10,  9,  7, 10,  2]])
```

---

*Edit* - If *`v` cannot occur in the first position*, then no need for `x_`:

```
>>> x
tensor([[ 9,  6,  5,  4, 10],
        [ 8,  7,  3,  5,  5],
        [ 4,  9, 10, 10, 10]])

>>> bp = (x == v).int().argmax(axis=1) - 1

>>> torch.stack([torch.cat([xi[:bpi], e, xi[bpi:]]) for xi, bpi in zip(x, bp)])
tensor([[ 9,  6,  5,  0,  4, 10],
        [ 8,  7,  3,  5,  0,  5],
        [ 4,  0,  9, 10, 10, 10]])
```

Comment: Indeed, a solution much better than the one I gave.

Comment: Bravo, sounds quite good for me. If I add two constraints, would the problem be easier or not change? 1. `v` never occurs on the first place. 2. If the row contains at least one `v`, then all the `v`s are consecutive and fill the rest part of the row. Still suppose `v=10`, then `[10, 5, 2, 8]`, `[5, 10, 9, 10]` and `[5, 10, 10, 9]` are all considered as illegal

Comment: If `v` never occurs in the first place, then it would remove the edge case and you wouldn't need `x_`. And simply do `bp = (x == v).int().argmax(axis=1) - 1` (we mask using `x` directly, also notice the `-1`), then use the same list comprehension as before on `zip(x, bp)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I tested and have a question now: would bp be calculated by `bp = (x == v).int().argmin(axis=1) + 1`?

Comment: `(x == v).int().argmin(axis=1)` gives you the index of the occurrence of `v`, on each row. Since you're looking to insert `e` **before** `v` you need to compute `index - 1`. Plus it has the benefit of solving the edge case: if there are no `v`, then the index is `0` (`argmax([0, 0, ..., 0])` is `0`), and `0 - 1 = -1` `i.e.` appended at the end. So no, `bp = (x == v).int().argmin(axis=1) + 1` wouldn't work.

Comment: I found the root cause why I produced different results...`argmin` and `argmax` behavior diffrently on torch 1.7.1 and torch 1.4.0 = =

Comment: Excuse me, I just found the result given by your supplemental solution doesn't match what I desired...

Comment: Can you share your input/output and desired output?

Comment: `tensor([[ 9,  6,  5,  4, 0, 10],
        [ 8,  7,  3,  5,  5,  0],
        [ 4,  9, 0, 10, 10, 10]])` is my desired output. The solution before your edit performs well for me but the one you appended seems doesn't worl properly

Comment: Sorry, you're right, the last column is still an issue when concatenating back since `xi[bpi:]` will always have an element whatever `bpi` value. You might want to stick with the first method for now. I'll keep looking.